# Remove None from tuple

Tags: python, tuples, nonetype

previous answers on how to remove None from a list dont help me!
I am creating a list of tuples with:

```
list(zip(*[iter(pointList)] *3))
```

So what i have is

```
[(object1,object2,object3),(object4,object5,object6),(object7,None,None)]
```

or

```
[(object1,object2,object3),(object4,object5,object6),(object7,object8,None)]
```

And i want to remove the None in the tuples (which only can occure at the last entry of the list!). So my desired output would be:

```
[(object1,object2,object3),(object4,object5,object6),(object7)]
```

or

```
[(object1,object2,object3),(object4,object5,object6),(object7,object8)]
```

What i thought would help me is:

```
filter(None,myList)
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Tuples are immutable - you can not change them in place.

Comment: ok so i have to construct my list otherwise?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tuples are **immutable** so once you construct a tuple you **cannot** alter its length or **set its elements**. Your only option is thus to construct *new* tuples as a post processing step, or don't generate these tuples in the first place.

## Post processing

Simply use a *generator* with the `tuple(..)` constructor in a *list comprehension* statement:

```
[tuple(xi for xi in x if xi is not None) for x in data]
```

## Alter the "packing" algorithm

With *packing* I mean converting a list of *m×n* items into *n* "slices" of *m* elements (which is what your first code fragment does).

If - like the variable name seems to suggest - **`pointList` is a list**. You can save yourself the trouble of using `zip`, and work with:

```
[tuple(pointList[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(pointList),3)]
```

directly. This will probably be a bit more efficient as well since here we never generate tuples with `None`s in the first place (given `postList` does not contain `None`s of course).

Comment: :) nice to hear, i did not know this (only Java background), i will try this

Comment: Ahh it looks like this doesnt work because i simplified my problem, i have acutally no iterable objects.

Comment: @lolio: but `data` is the output of your `list(..)` statement.

Comment: updated answer works perfectly, will accept in few minutes!

Comment: Noting that itertools.zip_longest appears to add 'None' by default (well not really) but it is very hard to 'exlude' - and it appears that post-processing is the only treatment for this methodology.  Is that correct or am I using itertools.zip_longest incorrectly?